# How to prove that every space can be decomposed into scattered and perfect subspace

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

How to prove the following claim:

**A space $X$ can be represented as the union of two disjoint subset $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is a scattered and $B$ satisfies $B=B'=:\{x: x \text{ is the accumulation point of B}\}$.**

> A [**scattered space**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269506/a-question-on-isolated-points) is a space for which every not empty subset has an isolated point.

**My idea:** Let $A$ is the set of all isolated points, $B=X\setminus A$. However, I'm not sure $B=B'$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to require that $B$ is either empty or not scattered at all (and allow $A$ to be empty as well).

Comment: @Paul I've tried to edit your title to describe your question better. It is better to use more descriptive title than just *How to prove the following claim?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem 1.7.10 in Engelking's General Topology gives the following hint how to solve prove this result:

> Show that if each member of a family $\mathcal A$ of subset of a space $X$ is dense
>   in itself, then the union $\bigcup \mathcal A$ is dense in itself. Note that if
>   $A\subset X$ is dense in itself, then the closure $\overline A$ is dense in itself.
>   Deduce from the above that every topological space can be represented as the union of two
>   disjoint sets, one of which is perfect and the second one is scattered.

A set is called *dense in itself* if $A\subseteq A'$.
*perfect set* = dense in itself and closed
*scattered set* = contains no non-empty dense in itself subset

---

If you simply take $A$ to be the set of all isolated points than for $X=\{0\}\cup\{1/n; n=1,2,\dots\}$ (with the usual Euclidean topology) you would bet $A=\{1/n; n=1,2,\dots\}$ and $B=\{0\}$, which is not the desired decomposition.

Comment: Why $A=\{1/n; n=1,2,\dots\}$ and $B=\{0\}$ is not the desired decomposition?

Comment: $B$ has no accumulation points, i.e., $B'=\emptyset$.