# Second countable scattered spaces are countable

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a second countable space and $X$ is scattered.

> **[A scattered space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269506/a-question-on-isolated-points)** is a space for which every not empty subset has an isolated point.

**How to show $X$ is countable?**

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Can those voting to close please explain to the OP *why* you are doing so?

Comment: The question as it is written fails to address a central point: why would anyone suspect a scattered space is countable in the first place?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is uncountable. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a countable base for $X$. Let $\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:|B|\le\omega\}$, let $A=\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0$, and let $Y=X\setminus A$. Then $|A|\le\omega$, so $Y$ is uncountable. Let $y\in Y$ be arbitrary. Suppose that $B\in\mathscr{B}$ and $y\in B$; then $B\nsubseteq A$, so $B\notin\mathscr{B}_0$, and therefore $|B|>\omega$. Finally, $|A|\le\omega$, so $|B\cap Y|=|B\setminus A|>\omega$. Thus, not only is $y$ not an isolated point of $Y$, but in fact every open nbhd of $y$ contains uncountably many points of $Y$.

Comment: I'm looking for a classical reference for this argument. Do you have any? Thanks

Comment: @Lorenzo: I didn’t, since I’ve always thought of it as folklore, but I’ve done a bit of digging and found that although the result is not stated explicitly there, essentially this argument appears in Kap. VIII, §3 of Felix Hausdorff, [*Grundzüge der Mengenlehre*](https://ia902205.us.archive.org/18/items/grundzgedermen00hausuoft/grundzgedermen00hausuoft.pdf), Leipzig, 1914. In my notation above he does explicitly show that $A$ is countable, from which this result follows immediately. (Mind you, it’s in German, and his notation differs significantly from current notation.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the meantime I've found a more recent reference that explicitly proves this result (through Cantor-Bendixson' argument):  Zbigniew Semadeni, *Banach spaces of continuous functions. Vol. I*, Section 8.5.

Comment: @Lorenzo: You’re very welcome!