# Q: about the definition of a scattered space

Tags: general-topology

In the book of "Counterexample in Topology", the authors define a scattered space as : "A space is called scattered if it contains no nonempty dense-in-itself subsets", which is different from definition in this post [A question on isolated points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269506/a-question-on-isolated-points). Which one is correct? In my understanding, the former does not exclude the case of perfect set and dense-in-itself does not imply perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions are equivalent. Saying that a non-empty set is [dense in itself](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself) is saying precisely that it has no isolated points. A perfect set is dense in itself, hence not scattered, though you are correct in thinking that a set that is dense in itself need not be perfect.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I prefer the latter since it is closer to "what really mean" :).

Comment: @yushang: You're welcome. (So do I.)